# jQuery addClass if not() has() element

Tags: jquery, selector, addclass

I would like to addClass=no-thumb to div.container if a.img-thumb has not `<img>` tag inside.

```
  <div class="container lrg-med">
    <a class="img-thumb" href="#"></a>
  </div>
```

Using the following but not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(".container.lrg-med").not(":has(img)").addClass("no-thumb");
```

Comment: NOTE: if a.img-thumb has not < img > tag inside!

Comment: Your code seem to work just fine?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6z91xwoc/1/

Comment: your fiddle works pretty nice but for some reason on my site is not working :/

Comment: ahhh found the issue!! im using infinite scroll, so the new content reloads every time i reach the bottom, how can i modify the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in `DOM Ready`

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery(".container.lrg-med").not(":has(img)").addClass("no-thumb");
});
```

Probably you are doing it before the DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

wait until DOM ready. for this use document.read

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".container.lrg-med").each(function() {
        if($('.img-thumb',$(this)).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("no-thumb");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: code is not wrapped in document.ready. he is not waiting to get DOM ready